# `git remote add` to home dir by `~` expression

Tags: ssh, git, home

I created git bare repository in my home directory like `~/git-repos/foo.git`.
To add a remote repository I typed like `git remote add origin ssh://username@hostname:10022~/git-repo/foo.git`.

But it fails with error `ssh: Could not resolve hostname hostname:10022~: Name or service not known`.

If I replace `~` to `/home/username`, then it works fine.

Is there way to use `~` expression for `git remote` with ssh protocols?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a `/` to indicate where the host spec ends and the path begins:

```
git remote add origin ssh://username@hostname:10022/~/git-repo/foo.git
```